# Is there anyway to implement Multi Column Filtering in Laravel Voyager Bread Browse View with Server Side Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, voyager

I have a bread for Some Reports generated on my Voyager Dashboard. See the screenshot.

[image]

And since there will be a huge amount of data available on this, i have enabled Server Side Pagination.
With this set-up i am now able to show the reports of a specific company only. I can use the filter options available at the top of the page.

[image]

But what if i need to filter multiple columns. Let's say, If i wanna show the reports of a particular company on a specific Invoice Date, or with a Specific Supplier. (I need to apply multiple falterings here)

Do you guys have any idea how i can achieve it.

Comment: for example you can use "where" array by every condition on your existing filters.

Answer (score 0):

It is a late answer, but hope it will help somebody.

According to the documentation (https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/overriding-files) you can override the 'browse', 'edit-add', 'read' and 'order' files.

To do so, you need to create the file you want to override under `resources/views/vendor/voyager/<slug-name>/` where the `<slug-name>` is the slug you have assigned for the table.

**And answering your question:**

In your case, you want to override the list, so make the following file - `resources/views/vendor/voyager/reports/browse.blade.php`

Find the original file, copy-paste it and add the filters there.

The original file is located in `vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/bread/browse.blade.php`